# Warning on missing custom javadoc tags

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

We create a custom Doclet for our projet to generate a specific documentation for our client.

We define some specific tags that are parsed by the doclet when we generate the documentation.

Do you know how to ask eclipse to add warning when those special tags are missing in our javadoc comments ?

Example of well formed javadoc:

```
/**
 * @dialogName TECK-01-E-608
 * @useVO ServiceVO
 * @useVO AgentVO
 */
public class MyDialog extends BaseDialogImpl {
...
```

If @dialogName is missing, the developper should have a warning in eclipse...

I look checkstyle a little bit, but I don't understand how to configure it to do such a thing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That should be detected by the **[CheckStyle "WriteTag"](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#WriteTag)** tool.
(I know you have looked at CheckStyle: this answer is there to mention a possible configuration):

```
<module name="WriteTag">
   <property name="tag" value="@dialogName"/>
   <property name="severity" value="warning"/> <!-- if not found, warning -->
   <property name="tagSeverity" value="ignore"/> <!-- if found, display nothing -->
</module>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try that.
But it seems to be "ignore" instead of "nothing".

Is-it possible to limit this check to only a subset of classes ? I want that only classes derived from BaseDialogImpl has this tag.

Comment: @flumins: thank you for the comment, I have fixed the answer. I am not sure you can apply it on a specific class hierarchy, even though you can run checkstyle on a subset of your project (but that doesn't address your point).